# Status 302 Found, when I try to access my web application instead of status 200

Tags: iis, web-applications, dns, round-robin, sitescope

Please help me in understanding why we get found 302 status. I googled and get to know that this is something to do with redirect. I have two web applications IIS servers and they configured for round robin DNS.

If I check it from fiddler sometimes I get status 302 instead of status 200, This does not happen every time I visit my website. Because of this HP site scope triggering alerts.

I am new to this error, Please Help me.

Comment: `302` response status code does not indicate an error, so if otherwise your site is behaving properly, you should configure HP site scope to: 1) either test some other URL that will always respond with `200` during normal operations, or 2) to treat `302` as success, not an error

Comment: Thank You :) @DusanBajic . How we can get always 200 response or in what scenarios we get 302 response.

Comment: `302` usually means "Moved Temporarily", with the new Location indicated in "Location" response header. There are many use cases for this, and the source is either in web server settings or in application itself (so no one but you can know). The one thing you can try is to look at "Location" header when you get 302 response, and modify your test to use that new location as target URL.